# How to improve the performance and accuracy of codescan.CodeScanner library of cn1

Tags: codenameone

I use the CodeScanner library of cn1 for QR code scan.
This library installs Barcode Scanner + simple for the scanning process.
But the performance and accuracy of Barcode Scanner + simple are poor.
Also Barcode Scanner + simple are depreciated reported by android before installing.
Any recommendations for replacing the cn1 library for QR code in ios and android?

Comment: What's deprecated? Can you point at the specific deprecation?

Comment: Android shows messages "This app is built for the old version of android. It may not function properly. Please check the update or contact the developer"

Comment: Just update the app or install a different QR reader app. We launch a 3rd party app using intent

Comment: I already installed a different QR reader app, but CodeScanner didn't launch it.
I don't quite understand.

Comment: Do you still have the old app installed? This is an Android intent, it launches an app and remembers it. You can reset intents via app settings too